# Load Data from Server in an Scrollview? (Dynamic - Content)

Tags: c#, objective-c, uiscrollview

How can I load Data (Text, Images, counter == One block ist Text, Image and Counter) and display it in the app on a maybe "UIScrollView"?.
The Problem is that it can can 10 block's or 100 block.
How can I display this block in the app like the "Wall" in the facebook app, Is this a ScollView? or a Table view?

I hope for tipps and hints :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView is the best option for wall like feature.
You need to set different for each cell type.

User this datasource method of UITableView for adjusting height

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And Configure your cell using

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Using UITableView over UIScrollView also gives you an additional feature of clicking the cell using this delegate method

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Which has to be done explicitly in case of a UIScrollView.

Cheers :)

Comment: Many thanks I will try this:) what is The advantig to Set The tableview over The scrollview? Ans is there a max height for The cells?